# Code works in jsfiddle but not in html document. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I am trying to create a sapui5 table from xml view but it doesn't seem to be working when I run it from visual studio but when I run it in jsfiddle it runs just fine. What is the reason for this?

Here is the code in my xmlTest.hml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">

    <script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
        <core:view xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                   xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
                   xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
                   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                   controllername="view.Main">
            <table:table width="100%" visiblerowcount="5" selectionmode="Single" editable="false" rows="{/data}">
                <table:title><label text="XML View"></label></table:title>
                <table:column>
                    <label text="Row Num" />
                    <table:template><textfield value="{rowNum}"></textfield></table:template>
                </table:column>
                <table:column>
                    <label text="ID" />
                    <table:template><textfield value="{id}"></textfield></table:template>
                </table:column>
                <table:column>
                    <label text="First Name" />
                    <table:template><textfield value="{name}"></textfield></table:template>
                </table:column>
                <table:column>
                    <label text="Email Address" />
                    <table:template><textfield value="{email}"></textfield></table:template>
                </table:column>

            </table:table>
        </core:view>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var aData = [
        { rowNum: 1, id: 42, name: "Anthony", email: "anthony@example.com" },
        { rowNum: 1, id: 42, name: "Anthony", email: "anthony@example.com" },
        { rowNum: 1, id: 42, name: "Anthony", email: "anthony@example.com" },
        ];
        sap.ui.controller("view.Main", {
            doSomething: function (oEvent) { }
        });

        var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
        });
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            data: aData
        });
        oView.setModel(oModel);
        oView.placeAt("content");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this code from visual studio I get the following errors:

[image]

These errors refer to [this file](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/table/table.js).

When I copy my code into jsfiddle it works just fine. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anthony1/yauw6mw8/1/).

Comment: Its not loading the JavaScript file... you need to make sure the path is correct.

Comment: In SAPUI5 / OpenUI5, it is best to fully adhere to the documented class name regarding case-sensitivity when referring to modules in XML view or fragment definitions. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/66395136/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you used lowercase <table:**t**able> instead of <table:**T**able>

The class name is `Table`, not `table`, and as such the file cannot be found (it's `Table.js`, not `table.js`)

In your JSFiddle you used the correct casing