# Referencing UI5 controls from Unix based systems fails

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, unix, sapui5

I'm creating a NodeJS based application with [sapui5](/questions/tagged/sapui5) framework but I'm facing a problem.

My app and view work well in my Windows 10 environment. Now I'm trying to continue developing it in Ubuntu but I'm facing this problem in `Checkbox.js`:

> The resource from *`http://localhost:8000/resources/sap/m/Checkbox.js`* was blocked due to MIME type ("type/html") mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to load 'sap/m/Checkbox.js' from resources/sap/m/Checkbox.js: script load error

As you can see, the control does exist:
[image: UI5 ComboBox source code in Firefox browser Ubuntu]

All other controls work normally. So when I remove the checkbox, my view works without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- See the section [Console shows *Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/xxxxx.js'*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/55db2bc60d694d1eacab4d4410f5dc46) from the doc.
- And the [reply by Tobias (tobiasso85)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2994#issuecomment-679994546) on the same issue:

  > Serving the resources depends on the server and its underlying filesystem used.
  >
  > While **Unix based systems are case-sensitive**,
  > Windows is **not** case-sensitive by default.

I.e. in your view, you must have somewhere `<Checkbox>` which works on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

→ Change it to `<CheckBox>`.

Same applies to `<ComboBox>`, `<LightBox>`, `<FlexBox>`, ... etc.
Bonus: there are `Breadcrumbs` from the `sap.m` lib **and** `BreadCrumbs` from the `sap.uxap` lib.

---

PS: when working in an IDE or editor that supports VSCode extensions, consider installing the official **[UI5 Language Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SAPOSS.vscode-ui5-language-assistant)**. That extension would've notified you that something is wrong:

> The "Combobox" name is neither a class name in the "sap.m" namespace nor an aggregation of the *<parentControl>* class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved my issue! And thanks again for tipo of Language assiistant, Ill use it!